# (Expected Declaration) error when using MPVolumeView

Tags: ios, media-player, audiokit, mpvolumeview

Im trying to setup MPVolumeView. Even though I declare the view, when putting "volumeView.addSubview(volView)" it gives me the error the error "expected declaration". I don't what I am doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import AudioKitUI
import AudioKit
import MediaPlayer

class SDViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var volumeView: UIView!

let volView = MPVolumeView()
    volumeView.addSubview(volView)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.insertSubview(volView, at: 0)
    volView.frame.origin.x = -1000

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class SDViewController hasn't been instantiated yet and therefore neither has volumeView.

You'll need to put that code inside a class method and call it from viewDidLoad() or something like that.

import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

```
class SDViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var volumeView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        volumeView.addSubview(volView)
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.insertSubview(volView, at: 0)
        volView.frame.origin.x = -1000
    }

}
```